# Is there a way to detach one Stack Exchange site from the rest of the sites and move it to a different account/email?

Tags: feature-request, network-profile

I'm beginning to posts answers / ask questions on the Workplace Stack Exchange site. I believe at a point I might write something which could be seen in a different light.

So, is it possible to detach/move my Workplace Stack Exchange account to a different email or account? Changing the display name doesn't really help.